# Let $O$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$ and suppose $f$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let $O$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$ and suppose $f$ is continuous. If $a$ and $b$ are numbers with $a < b$, prove that the set $\{u\in O: a<f(u)<b\}$ is open in $\mathbb{R^n}$.

A corollary from my textbook states that if the function $f:\mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $c$ is a real number then each of the sets $\{u\in \mathbb{R^n}: f(u) < c\}$ and $\{u\in \mathbb{R^n}: f(u) > c\}$ are open in $\mathbb{R^n}$. Therefore since $f$ is continuous by assumption it follows that since $\{u\in O: f(u) < b\}$ and $\{u\in O: f(u) > a\}$ are open in $\mathbb{R^n}$, their intersection, namely, $\{u\in O: a<f(u)<b\} = \{u\in O: a < f(u)\} \cap \{u\in O: f(u) < b\}$ is also open in $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Does this solution seem okay?

I am not sure if there is more I should do. Any feed back would be appreciated.

Comment: For me seems fine.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. Your proof looks good to me.

Comment: @RobArthan thank you for the comment

Comment: It sounds good. Well done!

Comment: @APCorreia Thank you!

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: @Shaun Advanced Calculus 2nd Edition by Fitzpatrick